# If ${\bf M}_{ij} = \min\{x_i,x_j\}$, is ${\bf M}$ positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be a set of $n$ positive real numbers, and consider the $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $\bf M$ whose $(i,j)$-th element is ${\bf M}_{ij} = \min\{x_i, x_j\}$. Is ${\bf M}$ positive semidefinite? I believe it is, but haven't been able to find or construct a proof.

Comment: Have you proved it for $n=2$?

Comment: The case where $x_i \le x_j$ when $i \lt j$ suggests a simple proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Suppose $0\le x_1\le x_2\le x_3$. Then
$$
\pmatrix{x_1&x_1&x_1\\ x_1&x_2&x_2\\ x_1&x_2&x_3}
=x_1\pmatrix{1&1&1\\ 1&1&1\\ 1&1&1}
+(x_2-x_1)\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 0&1&1}
+(x_3-x_2)\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1}.
$$

Comment: That nails it. Thank you very much!